# Workaround to accessing non-static member method from a static inner class

Tags: java

I have this non-static inner class that causes memory leaks, because it holds an implicit reference to the enclosing class:

```
private class CalendarScheduleUpdatedEventListener extends ScheduleUpdatedEventListener.Stub {

    @Override
    public void onScheduleUpdatedEvent() throws RemoteException {
        updateCalendar();
    }
}
```

In order to stop it from leaking, I need to make it static:

```
private static class CalendarScheduleUpdatedEventListener extends ScheduleUpdatedEventListener.Stub {

    @Override
    public void onScheduleUpdatedEvent() throws RemoteException {
        updateCalendar();-> Compiler error - trying to access a non-static...
    }
}
```

It is impossible to make `updateCalendar()` static because in it I access other non-static variables and it becomes a mess. What do I do?

Comment: Do you own the superclass?

Comment: I don't quite get why it has to be static. If you want to call a method of the enclosing class, you need that reference anyway. I don't really see the memory leak there.

Comment: What do you mean by _that causes memory leaks_? When the inner class  instance is GCed, the outer instance will be too (If there's no other reference). And when the inner instance remains in heap, the outer one has to remain too (Because you are calling the outer method anyway).

Comment: This would only leak memory if the event source retained a reference to the event handler but nothing else retained a reference to the outer class. What does the outer class do? Maybe you could refactor your code so the event listeners don't need to be inner classes?

Comment: @Codebender See my comment above. If there is no reference to the outer class except for the implicit reference created by the inner class, the outer class is considered a "leak" because it could otherwise be GC'ed.

Comment: @Greg, agreed... But if it's GC'ed what value would the inner instance hold? A proper fix would be to **unregister the listener** so that the inner instance can be GC'ed too...

Comment: @Codebender Yeah, it's hard to tell what the right approach would be without more context.

Comment: Guys I tried registering it multiple ways but somehow I couldnt properly do it, and didnt wanna overcomplicate the question. Anyway, the answers helped me fix my problem, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static class CalendarScheduleUpdatedEventListener extends ScheduleUpdatedEventListener.Stub {
    final WeakReference<Object> obj; //change <Object> to whatever type it is.

    CalendarScheduleUpdatedEventListener(Object x) {
        this.obj = new WeakReference<>(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScheduleUpdatedEvent() throws RemoteException {
        Object o = obj.get();
        if (o == null) {
            //because a WeakReference will be null if it has been garbage collected.
            return; //or throw some exception
        }
        o.updateCalendar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass in a reference to an instance of your outer class. And you need to make your static class public.

```
public static class CalendarScheduleUpdatedEventListener extends ScheduleUpdatedEventListener.Stub {

    @Override
    public void onScheduleUpdatedEvent(final TheOuterClass instance) throws RemoteException {
        instance.updateCalendar();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, but why is it not going to leak this time? Will the reference be GC'ed?

Comment: @J.K. As long as you are not holding on to the reference it cannot leak.

Comment: In general, I think this is a reasonable solution. However, I'm not sure that it will solve this specific issue. The outer class reference is leaked when the only remaining reference to it is the implicit reference created by the inner class. In order to pass an instance of `TheOuterClass` to the `onScheduleUpdatedEvent()` method, someone else must also have a reference to it; hence, it isn't being leaked.

Comment: @GregBrown I agree. In either way both instances have to be around if the instance of the inner class is to do anything useful. Making the inner class static decouples the life cycle of the two instances and it might be easier to understand what is going on. I.e. when what instance can be GCed.